# Circle numbers on edges of a graph

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $k$ vertices in a graph be given. Some pairs of vertices are connected by an edge, each edge is labeled either $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, or $\{2,3\}$. We can circle some of the numbers on the edges. If an edge is $\{1,2\}$, some vertex adjacent to it must be adjacent to a circled $1$ and a circled $2$. A similar requirement holds for $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ edges. Is it true that for any graph and labels, it is sufficient to circle at most $\lceil 3k/2\rceil$ numbers?

For instance, if $k = 3$ and the three edges have label $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3\}$, then it suffices to circle the first $1$, the first $3$, and the second $2$. It seems that $\lceil 3k/2\rceil$ numbers suffice in other examples as well. Is something known about this or similar problems?

Comment: What is "circle"? Is it the same as "color", or "label"?

Comment: @FedorPetrov An edge may have a label like $\{1,2\}$ on it. When we circle, we only circle one number at a time, like $1$. ("Circle" here is used as a verb, as in "circle the correct answer")

Comment: It is not clear from the question whether you allow both numbers to be circled on a single edge.  
If not, then a graph with a single edge is a counterexample, so I suppose that you allow it.  
An example that achieves $3k/2$ is given by a $K_4$ where non-adjacent edges receive the same labels.

Comment: @domotorp It is indeed allowed.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are looking for. First, $k$ is the total number of vertices in the graph or it is the number or vertices you are interested in? Second, in your examples with 3 edges labeled $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ it is not clear the difference. I fell like you build the same solution but in the first case you say it works, in the second, you say it does not.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698545/circle-numbers-on-edges-of-a-graph

Comment: @ViniciusdosSantos First, $k$ is the total number of vertices in the graph. Second, maybe my last paragraph confused you, I've removed it.

Comment: Thanks @RobPratt. I was about to post a solution equivalent to the one in the other post. Apparently, my (mis)understanding was the same.

Comment: Is there a motivation for this problem (such as a connection with some other problems)? How did you get to it?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I find the question interesting even without a motivation. I'm just looking for an excuse to spend more time thinking on it :-)

Comment: Are you interested in worse bounds? It seems I can circle $[5k/3]$ numbers to reach the goal…

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Given that the question seems to be difficult, sure, maybe that can give us some more ideas. I think I can get $2k$, and $3k/2$ is achievable in many special cases, but seems hard to prove generally.